# EPPlus with OpenXML and streams

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, epplus, memorystream

I am trying to automate a Powerpoint presentation. I am using OpenXML to navigate the powerpoint presentation up to the point that I find the Excel linked to a chart. Now I want to use EPPlus to load a datatable into one of the worksheets (because EPPlus has a simple LoadFromDataTable function whereas I think I would have to write lots of code to use OpenXML).
So my problem is this.

I have a PresentationDocument in memory. And I have navigated to the particular chart that I want to manipulate via:

```
doc.PresentationPart.SlideParts.ElementAt(0).ChartParts.ElementAt(0)
```

I get the Excel part using:

```
var stream = chartpart.EmbeddedPackagePart.GetStream()
```

Then I tried:

```
using(var pck = new ExcelPackage(stream)) {
    `do stuff;
    `pck.Save();
}
```

and then at the end I do a doc.PresentationPart.Presentation.Save but this hasn't changed the Presentation. I can change it using OpenXML instead with:

```
using (var xl =  Spreadsheet.Document.Open(stream, true))
{
    `do stuff;
    `xl.Close();
}
```

With everything else the same. So I guess either xl.Close() is doing stuff that pck.Save() isn't or I am using the stream incorrectly - can anyone advise?

Comment: Instead of doing `package.save()` what if you do `var bytes = package.GetAsByteArray()` and write it back to the original stream?  I havent dont much powerpoint coding but if that stream object is writable it might work.  Maybe post a working copy of your code to get more attention.

Comment: I ended up loading the data using OpenXML. Still having other issues to do with EmbeddedPackageParts and the cache but will post those separately.
thanks anyway